# Differences between Dungeon Defenders and Eternity

Tags: dungeon-defenders, version-differences, dungeon-defender-eternity

[Dungeon Defenders Eternity](http://store.steampowered.com/app/302270/) was announced on Steam offering the following description of what is new from the original game (italics mine):

> **New Missions** - Play the *best maps from the first game, plus four brand new missions* with more to come for free post-launch!
>   **New Features** - Visible armor, pet hatching & abilities, crafting, dodging, consumables, weapon-swapping, spellbinding, "permadeath" mode and a whole lot more!
>   **Secure Online Play** - No more hacking! Eternity runs on playverse's secure dedicated servers, so other Defenders can’t cheat their way to the top.
>   **Rebalanced & Retooled** - Our young heroes have an entirely *redesigned loot system* that fixes major issues from the original, giving them a fairer fight against the Old Ones’ rebalanced army!
>   **Cross Platform Play** - Take your heroes with you on the go and defend Etheria at anytime, from anywhere, with anyone! Download the Android version for Nvidia Tegra first, then stay tuned for an expanded launch on more Android devices, iPhones, and iPads later this year!

Does the new game include all the maps from the original?  What about DLC maps, characters, items, etc.?  What are the 4 new maps?  What does it mean when talking about rebalanced loot system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the new game include all the maps from the original? What about DLC maps, characters, items, etc.?

It includes all maps and challenges from both the original game and the Eternia Shards DLC. It does not have any holiday-themed maps or challenges yet (such as Valentines, Thanksgiving, or Christmas maps). You can also choose any and all heroes, including Summoner, EV, Barbarian and Jester.

> What are the 4 new maps?

The 4 new maps are Dread Dungeon, Arcane Library, Magus Citadel, and Embermount Volcano. The first 3 are additions to the original campaign, and Embermount appears to be the beginning of an entirely new campaign that goes beyond the Eternia Shards.

> What does it mean when talking about rebalanced loot system?

Loot is now server-side, meaning that they are taking significant and active measures to stop hacking (as it was REALLY prevalent in DD1 and they really didn't have a way to stop it other than banning the hacker when they were tattled on). Map rewards are no longer the absolute best weapons in the game, meaning we are going to see a lot more diversity when it comes to players and the weapons they wield (as opposed to seeing everyone holding Classics and Obsidian weapons).

It's also worth noting that textures are streamed in while you're playing the game, so when you first launch it, almost everything is going to be blurry, or "graphically inferior". In reality, it has almost exactly the same graphics the original Dungeon Defenders has.

For a comprehensive guide on the major differences between the two, read up on the Steam guide [Comparing Dungeon Defenders and DD Eternity.](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=290092757)

Comment: *"it includes all maps and challenges from both the original game and all of its expansions"* - Source?  According to [the Steam page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/302270/), it contains only " the best maps from the first game"...

Comment: I've personally checked, as I own both the original game and DDE. Upon closer inspection, the only thing it is missing are holiday event maps. I'll update my answer to include that information.

Comment: Nice answer Gigazelle. Can you confirm whether the "no solo option" is true? If so it's a real dealbreaker for me -- multiplayer is great when you've got a block of time, but otherwise...

Comment: They really needed to rebalance the drops. It was so difficult trying to farm up supremes, especially when items were despawning as fast as they were dropping by the time I got to that point u.u  And the other point that you pretty much needed a hacked item in order to get to the higher tiers of the later DLC maps.

Comment: Re: my query above -- reading DD forums, it looks like they've implemented private matches (that was fast!), still always on/shared tavern though apparently.

Answer (score 0):

- Visually inferior to the first game. By far.
- Third party overlay.
- Have to register for yet another account.
- No single player mode.
- No local co-op.
- Messy GUI, no explanation of things.
- Micro payments.
- Does not contain all maps.
- Very buggy.

Comment: Do you have a source at all for this?  I fail to see how an expansion/sequel can be visually inferior.

Comment: @Frank According to the steam reviews, it's a mobile game that was ported to PC.  Which is strange, since it's a UDK game.

Comment: It's not a mobile game that was ported to PC - it's a platform-agnostic game that can be played on mobile. The original Dungeon Defenders, however, WAS a mobile game that was ported to PC. The reviews for Dungeon Defenders Eternity are spewing hate right now because a lot of people think it's a cashgrab.

Comment: It turns out people were confused because the game downloads low-quality textures initially, then downloads all the high-quality textures while you play, in an attempt to increase first loading times.  So for the first few minutes the game looks like absolute garbage.

Comment: A lot of the hate is over the developers stating that they don't care enough about their customers to provide more than the very basic server side resources--- which are required for the game to be played! The developers made it worse when they revealed DDE is actually an alpha/beta of DD2, and its release IS a cash grab as they burned up so much on DD2. So yeah, mega fan hate--- when DDE isn't as fun, isn't as available, and everything but the squires have been nerfed. Devs state that is on purpose because they can't be bothered to balance a cash grab since they will abandon it soon.

Comment: BTW--- maybe later Trendy will shut up the developers posting this on Steam Community, but they are the actual game developers, so I'd say there is a lot of unhappiness in the DD dev team at this time.

Comment: As of this post, there is PRIVATE SESSION play available. There will never be local side only play. And the micro-payments are, for now at least (and forever according to the developers) limited to additional emote expressions ONLY for the character skins. It is NOT a pay to win and, again, according to the developers, will never be pay to win or pay to advance. They swear that all content will be always free in DDE except for skin emotes.